# User.name is still there although I removed it in git

Tags: git

I have 2 github accounts. I set one as global and one as local. I removed both of them in git using

`git config --global --unset user.name` and `git config --global --unset user.email`

The same thing for `--local`.

But when I do `git push origin master` it says :

```
ERROR: Permission to {username1}/{gitreponame} denied to {username2}.
```

which `username1` used to be the local username and `username2` the global one. Why is it still there ? How can I unset it ?

The original problem is that sometimes I can push to the account with local username and sometimes I cannot ! So I tried to unset the local and unset the global but it still uses my previously set global username and shows me error.

Comment: You can always manually edit the .gitconfig if need be

Answer (score 1):

You can try to manually remove your credentials in `~/.gitconfig` file.

Comment: The only thing related to my credentials in `~/.gitconfig` is : `[credential] helper = osxkeychain`. Do I have to add/remove anything to/from keychain ?

Comment: I just checked `keychain access` and looked for `github.com`. There are two entries for `internet password`. One is for `github.com` and one for `github.com/mac`. and both of them have usernames which I don't want to use. I deleted everything related to `git*` and still I receive the same error.

Comment: Did you try to set local username/email to {username1} in problem repository again?

Comment: Yes I did, but it doesn't take effect. When I clone it , I can work with it w/o any problem for some time , until I go to another repository and again when I come back , the problem is there.